# Different bindings for left and right Option key in OS X

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, terminal

Is it possible to have a META key on left Option while at the same time being able to use right Option for Alt+2=@ and other things typical to Swedish/Danish layouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use a [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) like this with KeyRemap4MacBook:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <appdef>
    <appname>APPLETERMINAL</appname>
    <equal>com.apple.Terminal</equal>
  </appdef>
  <item>
    <name>terminalmeta</name>
    <identifier>terminalmeta</identifier>
    <only>APPLETERMINAL</only>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::A, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::A</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::B, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::B</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::C, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::C</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::D, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::D</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::E, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::E</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::F, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::F</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::G, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::G</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::H, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::H</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::I, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::I</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::J, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::J</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::K, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::K</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::L, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::L</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::M, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::M</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::N, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::N</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::O, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::O</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::P, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::P</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::Q, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::Q</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::R, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::R</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::S, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::S</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::T, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::T</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::U, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::U</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::V, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::V</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::W, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::W</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::X, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::X</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::Y, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::Y</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::Z, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::Z</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEY_0, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::KEY_0</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEY_1, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::KEY_1</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEY_2, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::KEY_2</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEY_3, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::KEY_3</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEY_4, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::KEY_4</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEY_5, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::KEY_5</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEY_6, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::KEY_6</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEY_7, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::KEY_7</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEY_8, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::KEY_8</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEY_9, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::KEY_9</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::BACKQUOTE, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::BACKQUOTE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::BACKSLASH, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::BACKSLASH</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::BRACKET_LEFT, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::BRACKET_LEFT</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::BRACKET_RIGHT, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::BRACKET_RIGHT</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::COMMA, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::COMMA</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::DOT, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::DOT</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::EQUAL, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::EQUAL</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::MINUS, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::MINUS</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::QUOTE, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::QUOTE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::SEMICOLON, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::SEMICOLON</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::SLASH, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::SLASH</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEYPAD_0, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::KEYPAD_0</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEYPAD_1, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::KEYPAD_1</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEYPAD_2, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::KEYPAD_2</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEYPAD_3, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::KEYPAD_3</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEYPAD_4, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::KEYPAD_4</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEYPAD_5, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::KEYPAD_5</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEYPAD_6, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::KEYPAD_6</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEYPAD_7, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::KEYPAD_7</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEYPAD_8, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::KEYPAD_8</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEYPAD_9, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::KEYPAD_9</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEYPAD_CLEAR, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::KEYPAD_CLEAR</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEYPAD_COMMA, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::KEYPAD_COMMA</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEYPAD_DOT, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::KEYPAD_DOT</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEYPAD_EQUAL, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::KEYPAD_EQUAL</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEYPAD_MINUS, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::KEYPAD_MINUS</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEYPAD_MULTIPLY, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::KEYPAD_MULTIPLY</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEYPAD_PLUS, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::KEYPAD_PLUS</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEYPAD_SLASH, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::KEYPAD_SLASH</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::DELETE, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::DELETE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::ENTER, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::ENTER</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::ESCAPE, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::ESCAPE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::FORWARD_DELETE, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::FORWARD_DELETE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RETURN, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::RETURN</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::SPACE, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::SPACE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::TAB, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::TAB</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::CURSOR_UP, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::CURSOR_UP</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::CURSOR_DOWN, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::CURSOR_DOWN</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::PAGEUP, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::PAGEUP</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::PAGEDOWN, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::PAGEDOWN</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::HOME, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::HOME</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::END, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::END</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::UK_SECTION, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE, KeyCode::UK_SECTION</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

`__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::OPTION_L, KeyCode::VK_NONE, Option::KEYTOKEY_BEFORE_KEYDOWN, KeyCode::ESCAPE` wouldn't work for pressing multiple keys while holding option.

Mapping the right option to forward delete or multiple modifier keys:

`<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::OPTION_R, KeyCode::FORWARD_DELETE</autogen>`

`<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::OPTION_R, KeyCode::CONTROL_L, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L | ModifierFlag::OPTION_L | ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L | ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L</autogen>`

See the source for the [key code values](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/blob/master/src/bridge/generator/keycode/data/KeyCode.data) and [predefined settings](http://raw.github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/master/Tests/lib/string/data/checkbox.xml).

iTerm supports changing just one option key to meta:

[image]

Comment: I guess you had the best answer but my decision is to not use third party software for this and accept that I cannot accomplish it natively.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify some behavior using third party software such as [KeyRemap4Macbook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/list.html), but I doubt it will be exactly as you imagine.

**Change Option_R Key (Right Option)**

- Option_R to Command_L
- Option_R to Command_R
- Option_R to Control_L
- Option_R to Control_L (only in virtual machine)
- Option_R to Control_R
- Option_R to Control_R (only in Emacs, Terminal, X11)
- Option_R to Fn
- Command_R+Option_R to Fn
- Option_R to Option_R
  (+ When you type Option_R only, send Command+Space)
- Option_R to Option_R+Shift_L
- Option_R to Delete
- Option_R to End
- Option_R to End (only in virtual machine, RDC)
- Option_R to End (only in virtual machine, RDC)
  (+ Shift+Option_R to Shift+End,Control_L+C)
- Option_R to End (only in virtual machine, RDC)
  (+ Shift+Option_R to Shift+End,Command_L+C)
- Option_R to Enter
- Option_R to Forward Delete
- Option_R to Left-Arrow
- Option_R to PageDown
- Option_R to Command_L+Right-Arrow (except virtual machine, RDC)
- Option_R to Command_L+Right-Arrow (except virtual machine, RDC)
  (+ Shift+Option_R to Command_L+Shift_L+Right-Arrow,Command_L+C)
- Option_R to Command_L+Right-Arrow (except virtual machine, RDC)
  (+ Shift+Option_R to Command_L+Shift_L+Right-Arrow,Control_L+C)
- Option_R to Command_L+Right-Arrow
- Option_R to Semicolon
- Option_R to Space
- Option_R to Command+Control+Option+Shift+F1

You can try using one of these combinations and [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/ukelele) to change your keyboard layout so it has the desired effect.